# Using mongo gems in Rails 5 -- should it be this hard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, bundler

Am I missing something incredibly obvious?

I generate a new rails 5 application, and per the mongo doc, added the gem to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongo', '~> 2.4'
```

`bundle install` installs the gem (and gem dependencies) fine, but when I just try to bring up a rails console:

```
$ rails c
Could not find bson-4.2.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Are there some further installation instructions buried somewhere?

FWIW, `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin14]`

and

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.2
```

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The runtime dependencies for gem 'mongo', '~> 2.4' is

```
gem 'bson', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.1'
```

please check ref: 
https://rubygems.org/gems/mongo/versions/2.4.1

so you need to install the above gem 'bson'.

Answer (score 0):

Try these gems by replacing them in gem file .It works for me with Rails 5

```
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid.git'
gem 'bson_ext'
```